# Redirect old RDS traffic to the new RDS in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-rds, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc

Old database endpoint : `old.cy336nc8sq5l.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`

New database endpoint : `new.cy336nc8sq5l.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`

Above endpoints are automatically created by AWS, at the time of creation of RDS instance

I have tried setting up CNAME for `old.cy336nc8sq5l.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` with value `new.cy336nc8sq5l.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` but it did not worked.For this I have to create a new Hosted zone in `route53` name `cy336nc8sq5l.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`

However, If a setup a CNAME in other hosted zone for any url like abc.example.com with value `new.cy336nc8sq5l.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` works like a charm. The old rds url has been used in multiple application I cannot take a risk to completely abandon, the best way is to use some kind of redirection.

In addition to it, any CNAME under the `cy336nc8sq5l.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` Hosted zone is not working.

How can I fix this? Please also suggest what is the best practice for redirection rds traffic? I knew for the new DB endpoint, I will create a new custom CNAME and will use that going forward rather that just using the default one. All suggestions are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't add any records for the domain **cy336nc8sq5l.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com**, because you don't control it, Generally you will be able to create any hosted zones like **google.com** etc but it won't get reflect unless you change the NS record and SOA records from the original DNS provider to point yours, you can't it with aws rds domains. you can confirm it by doing

```
dig +short -t ns cy336nc8sq5l.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

If above results returns your NS records then you control that domain.

To have this kind of flexibility in future, i would suggest a way create a private zone like mydb.com and have A record like master.mydb.com with value **old.cy336nc8sq5l.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com** and when you want to switch to another endpoint just switch it in route53, after TTL expires the connections will start coming to new endpoint, since you are  making a change, its better to start using this way.

Also for your case, after you switch to new endpoint, you can check the connections count in the old DB to know if its being referred somewhere and by running `show processlist;`, you will be able to know which IP, its being used.

Comment: For future, I know , I will use my private host zone. But I have 30 + application using the same DB point. I cannot go to all the 30 application and change the DB endpoint. Although, show processlist will help a lot

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is that you are going to have to update all 30 applications to use the new DB endpoint.  If you are going to be deleting databases & recreating them like this regularly, then configure your databases to use a name in a zone you control, and create a CNAME to whatever database endpoint is current.

You *may* be able to create a temporary solution by adding an entry to /etc/hosts (assuming your clients are running linux - I believe this is also possible on Windows, but it has been a long time) that maps the current IP for the new database to the old hostname.  But this is probably just as much work as updating the application to use the new database.  It will also fail if you are running a multi-AZ database and have a failover event.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `DB identifier` can help in some way.

Select your cluster -> `Modify` -> change `DB cluster identifier`

You will keep your old database with difference endpoint, then change new DB to new endpoint.

But I love `/etc/hosts` solution as simple and safe.

Comment: Will check this out